# SQL Combining These Two Tables Into One

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, append, union

What would be the MS Access SQL to combine these two tables? Table1 has column A, B, and C. Table2 has A, D, and E. I want the final result to be A,B,C,D,E where (join) Table1 A equals Table2 A.

Union/UnionAll tells me the columns don't match. Insert into gives me a similar error. Thanks in advance for any help. (Sorry this is probably a noob question)

Comment: Do you mean combined the result of a query or permanently?

Comment: I want a new table created which is a combination of Table1 and Table2 (or add the Table2 fields to Table1). I posted an answer that queries correctly, but when I tried to change it as a `SELECT INTO` it said "Record Too Large"

Answer (score 1):

UNION is for combining data with equal columns, what you need is a JOIN

SELECT t1.A,B,C,D,E FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A

Comment: Won't this throw an error for an "ambiguous column name"?  Might need to refer to A by t1.A (or t2.A).

Comment: Yes, you are right - this could happen, I will change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

select a.A,a.B,a.C,b.D,b.E from Table1 a, Table2 b where a.A==b.B;

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
SELECT Table1.*, Table2.*
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.A=Table2.A;
```

Comment: Although now I don't know how to dump that query into a new table

Comment: I tried `SELECT Table1.*, Table2.* INTO Table3
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.A=Table2A;` but it said "Record Too Large" (since there's like 170 fields on Table1, and 15 on Table2). UGH what now?

Comment: see my answer I just tested it in MS Access 2003 and it worked.

Comment: @brettville: You've exceeded the maximum allowed size for a row with all those columns (not with their number, possibly, but with the total data size per row, although there likely is a limitation for the number of columns per row too in MS Access). One other potential issue with that particular query might be that it might contain identical column names. I wouldn't trust masked column lists in such cases, even if there was no risk of exceeding the maximum row size.

Comment: @AndriyM I used A,B,C, etc for simplification. There are no identical columns except for the joining column "boc_num_string". It's super annoying to me that a 20 year old database (superbase) has looser limitations than Access 2003. SuperBase can have a table with 500+ field names, no problem. Not that it's a good idea. Obviously the database I'm working with isn't using best practices, but it drives me nuts Access has so many short falls.

Comment: @brettville: According to [specs](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-specifications-HP005186808.aspx "Access specifications (MS Office Access 2003)"), the maximum number of fields is 255, which *is* rather modest yet it's greater than the total number of fields in your two tables. So, as I said earlier, it must be the total data size per record that the two field sets exceed. On the other note, the two `boc_num_string` fields would indeed cause the query to fail in the absence of the former issue. You can't have identical field names when the query contains an `INTO` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in MS Access 2003 and it worked:

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t1.C, t2.D, t2.E
INTO Table3
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.A = t2.A
```

I got all data from table1 and table2 in my new table.